# Having hard time figuring out the best attribute to use with cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using this attribute `%NOTFOUND` with this cursor is giving me issues. I also tried using `%FOUND`. Is There a better option? It keeps returning the Else even if the cursor comes back with something in it or not. I want it to send the first email if the cursor has something and the second one if the cursor has nothing.

```
CURSOR crs IS
 select *
 from user_objects
 where status = 'INVALID';
BEGIN

 OPEN crs;

Loop

  FETCH crs bulk collect INTO messages limit 10;
  EXIT WHEN message. count = '0';

 End IF;

  for indx in     messages.FIRST .. messages.LAST
  loop 
    email_body := email_body||CHR(10)||'OBJECT NAME: '||messages(indx).OBJECT_NAME||', OBJECT TYPE: '||messages(indx). OBJECT_TYPE||', STATUS: '||messages(indx).STATUS;
  end loop;
END LOOP;



 IF CRS%NOTFOUND THEN
     Email_body := email_body||CHR(10)|| '' ||CHR(10)||'All of these objects are invalid in your database. Please troubleshoot the issue. Thank you.'
     DBMS_OUTPUT_LINE(email_body||'Invalid obj.';
    ELSE 
     Email_body := 'There are no invalid objects in your database. Thank You.';
      DBMS_OUTPUT_LINE(email_body||'No Invalid obj.';
    END IF;
```

Comment: Please update with the code related to declaring and opening the cursor. Assuming you have opened the cursor of course.

Comment: @nola You maybe fogot to add FETCH after open cursor?

Comment: When using BULK COLLECT, check the size of your collection (in your case, `messages`) instead of using cursor attributes. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try this for test (i think more readable and shorter):

```
declare
    email_body varchar2( 4000 ) := '';
    l_invalid_objects_list varchar2( 4000 ) := '';
begin
l_invalid_objects_list := '';
for i in ( select OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS from user_objects where status = 'INVALID' and rownum <= 10 ) --limited to 10 records
loop
    l_invalid_objects_list := l_invalid_objects_list||CHR(10)||'OBJECT NAME: '||i.OBJECT_NAME||', OBJECT TYPE: '||i. OBJECT_TYPE||', STATUS: '||i.STATUS;
end loop;
if length( l_invalid_objects_list ) > 0 then 
    email_body := email_body||CHR(10)|| '' ||CHR(10)||l_invalid_objects_list||CHR(10)|| '' ||CHR(10)||'All of these objects are invalid in your database. Please troubleshoot the issue. Thank you.';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(email_body||'Invalid obj.');
else
    Email_body := 'There are no invalid objects in your database. Thank You.';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(email_body||'No Invalid obj.');
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use a bulk operation and that you want to do this in batches of 10 even though it might be overkill for the functionality.
So . . .  you need to declare a table type based on the cursor (ROWTYPE) then declare a variable based on the type.
You want to add to the email_body for each object and when you've looped through the lot it looks like you want another message saying if there were any invalid objects.

Using %NOTFOUND is not right here as you exit your loop when the messages.COUNT = 0. When it is 0 the cursor will always be %NOTFOUND so you're always getting the INVALID option.
I've used a boolean that is set to TRUE as soon as you have at least one invalid object and that is checked instead of the %NOTFOUND.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR crs
   IS
      SELECT *
      FROM   user_objects
      WHERE  status = 'INVALID';

   TYPE work_recs IS TABLE OF crs%ROWTYPE;
   messages work_recs;

   lbol_invalid_objects BOOLEAN := FALSE;
   email_body  VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
   OPEN crs;

   LOOP
      FETCH crs BULK COLLECT INTO messages LIMIT 10;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT - '||messages.COUNT);

      EXIT WHEN messages.COUNT = '0';

      lbol_invalid_objects := TRUE;

      FOR indx IN messages.FIRST .. messages.LAST
      LOOP
         email_body := email_body||CHR(10)||'OBJECT NAME: '||messages(indx).OBJECT_NAME||', OBJECT TYPE: '||messages(indx). OBJECT_TYPE||', STATUS: '||messages(indx).STATUS;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   IF lbol_invalid_objects THEN
      email_body := email_body||CHR(10)|| '' ||CHR(10)||'All of these objects are invalid in your database. Please troubleshoot the issue. Thank you.'
      dbms_output.put_line('Invalid obj.');
   ELSE
      email_body := 'There are no invalid objects in your database. Thank You.';
      dbms_output.put_line('No Invalid obj.');
   END IF;
END;
```